# Cannot display iAd on iPhone view only for Universal app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, iad

I am trying to display an iAd banner for a Universal app (iPhone/iPad)

The iAd is displayed fine for the iPad, but for the iPhone, I get the message;
ADBannerView: WARNING A banner view (0x5743350) has an ad but may be obscured.

The code that I use is as follows;

```
    ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:adView];
```

Please help me fix the issue. Also what should the Base SDK be set to such that it works on maximum devices ?

Comment: This is presumably the code at banner creation time as you're placing it outside the view. The error message comes when the ad is loaded so in the delegate method bannerViewDidLoadAd where you would slide the ad back into view, can you maybe post this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your y-coordinate in CGRectMake for adview.frame is set to the height of self.view.frame, effectively making your origin (0.0, 460.0).

Comment: But i am not sure how it works for the iPad...I am looking for common code for both iPhone and iPad...